# How do I know ffmpeg-php is installed?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I just followed the instructions from this link on how to install ffmpeg-php on my dedicated server: http://www.ndchost.com/wiki/server-administration/install-ffmpeg

At the bottom, it says to run the command `php -i|grep ffmpeg` and if it outputs the following lines then it is installed:

```
ffmpegffmpeg support (ffmpeg-php) => enabled
ffmpeg-php version => 0.6.0
ffmpeg.allow_persistent => 0 => 0
```

When I run it, it gives me this:

```
ffmpeg
ffmpeg-php version => 0.6.0-svn
ffmpeg-php built on => Jul 18 2014 08:46:12
ffmpeg-php gd support  => enabled
ffmpeg libavcodec version => Lavc52.108.0
ffmpeg libavformat version => Lavf52.93.0
ffmpeg swscaler version => SwS0.12.0
ffmpeg.allow_persistent => 0 => 0
ffmpeg.show_warnings => 0 => 0
PWD => /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0
_SERVER["PWD"] => /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0
_ENV["PWD"] => /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0
```

I got 2/3 lines, but the one is not character-for-character the same.

Is `ffmpegffmpeg support (ffmpeg-php) => enabled` the same as `ffmpegffmpeg support (ffmpeg-php) => enabled` in this context?

EDIT:
Running this command `ffmpeg -version` gives me this result:

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r26402, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 18 2014 08:41:45 with gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
  configuration: --enable-libmp3lame --disable-mmx --enable-shared
  libavutil     50.36. 0 / 50.36. 0
  libavcore      0.16. 1 /  0.16. 1
  libavcodec    52.108. 0 / 52.108. 0
  libavformat   52.93. 0 / 52.93. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 3 / 52. 2. 3
  libavfilter    1.74. 0 /  1.74. 0
  libswscale     0.12. 0 /  0.12. 0
FFmpeg SVN-r26402
libavutil     50.36. 0 / 50.36. 0
libavcore      0.16. 1 /  0.16. 1
libavcodec    52.108. 0 / 52.108. 0
libavformat   52.93. 0 / 52.93. 0
libavdevice   52. 2. 3 / 52. 2. 3
libavfilter    1.74. 0 /  1.74. 0
libswscale     0.12. 0 /  0.12. 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

`% ffmpeg -version`

Comment: added an edit to my question with the output from that command

Comment: According to your new edit it looks like you have FFmpeg installed.

Comment: but what about ffmpeg-php?

Comment: It says `ffmpeg-php version => 0.6.0`. I take that as ffmpeg-php also is installed. Why don't you try it out and see if it works?

Comment: Or you can try `phpinfo();` and search for ffmpeg.